# How do I add a Rackspace cloud database as a data source in PhpStorm?

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, datagrip, rackspace-cloud

I've added the host URL (`{hash}.rackspaceclouddb.com`), port 3306, and I'm using the same user and password that has access to everything via PhpMyAdmin, but I'm getting a failure when I test the connection. I understand that they run their instances on a private network, which I'm sure is causing the difficulty. Is there some trick I'm not aware of, or is it not possible?

Error message:

> Failed: Communications link failure. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Where PhpMyAdmin is running: on your local computer and there on Rackspace servers as well? Normally nobody exposes (allows direct access) to a DB over the internet. It's all private network (as you have mentioned). But you should be able to access it via SSH tunnel that PhpStorm and other IDEA-based IDEs support. So I suggest you check your Rackspace account for this kind of information, set up SSH in PhpStorm and then make the DB data source connection using that. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-ssh-and-ssl.html#ssh

Comment: Or perhaps you have done all that already but it still does not work for you?.. Will other DB clients that you run on your local computer are able to connect using the same means?

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions, we've had a similar issue when establishing a connection with MySql. Please update DataGrip to the latest version. Also, make sure to download the latest MySql driver version available in DataGrip.